# swrevealcontroller not working after navigation to homepage

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swrevealviewcontroller

I am new to Swift and I am trying to implement side navigation using `SWrevealcontroller`

I have a root VC which has a button when click on this button I am navigating to UITabBarController

Here is how my storyboard looks like (below)

[image]

and this is how I am navigating on button click

```
@IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

This is my code in `FirstViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        barButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

But I am getting error at line when I navigate from root VC to UITabBarController

`self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())`

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Can someone help me what is wrong here.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present your `RevealViewController` instead of the `UITabBarController`.

Add a `Storyboard ID` to your `RevealViewController`:

[image]

And then present it in your `clickButton(_:)` function, like this:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RevealViewControllerID")
self.present(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: you mean, I have to change my code like this

`@IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController
        self.revealViewController()?.setFront(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }`

But after changing this I am not able to navigate.

Comment: @Rigsby you are not able to navigate from the side menu or from the tabbar?

Comment: I am clicking on that orange button from the first VC, on click of that, I am trying to navigate, clickButton is the method called on orange button click

Comment: @Rigsby oh, that supposed to present the `TabBarController` along with the side menu?

Comment: @Rigsby sorry, I got it wrong. Then you need to present your `RevealViewController` instead of your `TabBarController`. (the one that is left of your `TabBarController`) Try to add a `Storyboard ID` to your `RevealViewController`, instantiate it and then present it.